# Is user_id length limited to 36 characters on Firebase JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Because the data governance requirements for my project, I need to hash the `user-id` value with sha256 (sha256 value: 64 characters) and store in the `user-id` field in `firebase/GA4/bigquery`.

In `Firebase analytic native APP sdk`(iOS/Android), I already confirm the hashed user-id stored in `firebase/GA4/bigquery` correctly (64 characters).
But in `Firebase analytic JS SDK`, I found the user-id in debug view is truncated only to first 36 characters, and the user-id in bigquery is also only 36 characters.

The official document doesn't describe whether or not there is this limitation. So, I want to make sure it.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#uid) there is no maximum length for the user ID.

The web client **may** have truncated the user ID 36 characters, which is being reconsidered at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the document has no description about it. After my implementation, it's truncated to 36 characters. It may be related to the issue in GA. And there is no this length limitation of userid in BQ.